# Cannot delete old kernels / sda full

Tags: apt, kernel, uninstall

SDA1 is full and I cannot run upgrades

```
root@ubuntu-nextcloud:/home/nextcloud# df -h
Filesystem                              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                                    6.9G     0  6.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                   1.4G  9.0M  1.3G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--nextcloud--vg-root  585G  273G  282G  50% /
tmpfs                                   4.0G     0  4.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                   5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                   4.0G     0  4.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0                              179M  179M     0 100% /snap/nextcloud/1474
/dev/loop1                               80M   80M     0 100% /snap/core/1689
/dev/loop3                              161M  161M     0 100% /snap/nextcloud/1337
/dev/loop2                               79M   79M     0 100% /snap/core/1441
/dev/loop5                              179M  179M     0 100% /snap/nextcloud/1540
/dev/loop4                               79M   79M     0 100% /snap/core/1577
/dev/sda1                               472M  461M     0 100% /boot
tmpfs                                   829M     0  829M   0% /run/user/1000
```

There is a bunch of old kernels and I would like to remove them.

```
root@ubuntu-nextcloud:/home/nextcloud# dpkg --list | grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic       4.4.0-31.50                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic       4.4.0-59.80                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic       4.4.0-62.83                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-63-generic       4.4.0-63.84                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic       4.4.0-64.85                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-66-generic       4.4.0-66.87                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-67-generic       4.4.0-67.88                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic       4.4.0-70.91                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic       4.4.0-71.92                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iF  linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic       4.4.0-72.93                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iF  linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic       4.4.0-75.96                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic 4.4.0-31.50                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-59-generic 4.4.0-59.80                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-62-generic 4.4.0-62.83                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-63-generic 4.4.0-63.84                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-64-generic 4.4.0-64.85                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-66-generic 4.4.0-66.87                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-67-generic 4.4.0-67.88                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-70-generic 4.4.0-70.91                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iF  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-71-generic 4.4.0-71.92                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iU  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic 4.4.0-72.93                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iU  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-75-generic 4.4.0-75.96                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iU  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-77-generic 4.4.0-77.98                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iU  linux-image-generic                4.4.0.77.83                                amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

Whatever I try, it does not work:

```
root@ubuntu-nextcloud:/home/nextcloud# sudo apt-get purge linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-77-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-77-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-77-generic but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: thermald but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Next try

```
root@ubuntu-nextcloud:/home/nextcloud# purge-old-kernels --keep 3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-59-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-62-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-63-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-63-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-64-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-66-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-66-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-67-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-67-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-70-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-77-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-77-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-77-generic but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: thermald but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Next try

```
root@ubuntu-nextcloud:/home/nextcloud# dpkg -l linux-* | awk '/^ii/{ print $2}' | grep -v -e `uname -r | cut -f1,2 -d"-"` | grep -e [0-9] | grep -E "(image|headers)" | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-77-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-77-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-77-generic but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: thermald but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Last idea

```
    root@ubuntu-nextcloud:/home/nextcloud# apt-get autoremove -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-image-4.4.0-77-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc-4.4.0 | linux-source-4.4.0 linux-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-4.4.0-77-generic
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
12 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/21.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 66.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 414438 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.4.0-77-generic_4.4.0-77.98_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-77-generic (4.4.0-77.98) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-77-generic_4.4.0-77.98_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/abi-4.4.0-77-generic' to '/boot/abi-4.4.0-77-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-77-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-77-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-77-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-77-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-77-generic_4.4.0-77.98_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@ubuntu-nextcloud:/home/nextcloud#
```

EDIT: Only temporarily moving old kernel files to an temp folder worked out, by creating a small amount of space and letting the commands work again.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /boot
```

Locate the oldest kernel in the `/boot` directory:

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -P Full_name_of_oldest_kernel
sudo apt autoremove --purge
```

There are a variety of ways to automate the above command for sustainability.  A `cron job`,for example.

Comment: Are you sure the command would have worked with no space left? That was the problem with all the rest. Or do you mean first remove something old and then run the command? Anyway: I got it worked with the solution I posted. Thxs!

Answer (score -1):

I got it worked:

1. Create a temp folder (for example /home/user/temp)
2. Run uname -r to figure it which kernel is running and do not touch this!
3. Move the kernel files of a specifig unused kernel to this temp folder.

You will get some space and the command should work again.
Source: http://natesbox.com/blog/ubuntu-unable-to-installupdate-packages-full-boot-partition/

PS: I forgot to set autoremove for this server for automatic updates. I think this may have caused the issue.

Comment: I moved it back and was able to remove it.
what is the correct command for use dpkg in such case?
I just needed to uncomment the autoremove comment in unattended-upgrades. This was just missing on this server.

Comment: I tried to use dpkg (see the third attempt). It did not worked. But thxs for the fast downvote...

Comment: it seems like you did not even read my text once.
1. There were more than one kernel and your solution did not worked for any of them
2. Anyway I tried the command when the files have been in place
3. My solution worked and it was the only thing that worked

Comment: I'll remove my downvote if you add a Step 4 that moves the temp stuff back to where it belongs. Instructions should include clean-up. And fix the grammar.

Comment: You are very rude and respectless. I don't owe you anything and will not follow your commands, begging for an upvote... Also learn to read first, have some respect and judge later...